# Ecmascript6 with browserify

Tags: babeljs, browserify, package.json

i have a little question about compiled JS (Ecmascript 6) with browserify.
I make my package.json like this :

```
{
  "name": "myApp",
   "main": "app.js",
   "scripts": {
        "build-map": "browserify -e app.js -o ./public/js/bundle.js",
        "start": "node app.js"
   },
   "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.3.0",
        "babel-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.8.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.0.0",
        "babel-runtime": "^5.8.0",
        "babelify": "^7.2.0",
        "browserify": "^13.0.0"
   },
   "browserify": {
     "transform": [
       [
         "babelify",
         {
           "presets": [
             "es2015"
           ]
         }
       ]
     ]
   }
}
```

But i have seen this example :

```
    {
      "name": "test-browserify",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "scripts": {
        "build": "browserify main.js --transform [ babelify --plugins [ transform-es2015-modules-commonjs ] ] | uglifyjs -c -m > bundle.js"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.22.0",
        "babelify": "^7.3.0",
        "browserify": "^14.0.0",
        "uglify-js": "^2.7.5"
      }
 }
```

Is this the same thing or there-is any differences ? I begin with NodeJS and it's a bit confuse :).

If I want to prefer webpack to browserify, how would be the package.json ?

Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is relevant if you want to make a reusable module. As if someone puts your project as a dependency, babelify will be applied  automatically at runtime.

In the second solution, babelify will be applied only when you build your project.